# How do I delete 1 of 2 One Drives from a Dell laptop?

Tags: windows-11, onedrive, dell-inspiron, replacement, remote-assistance

My previous job was remote. Once my contract expired, they let me keep the laptop provided. I am able to use it but a message requesting me to log in into my previous job's drive pops constantly. I have my own personal One Drive installed but need to delete the One Drive from my past job. I am not an IT tech or something like that and need help.  Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Either you reinstall Windows from scratch or ask your former IT staff to remove the domain account.

Comment: try with "disk manager " app in windows 11

Comment: @Petepf Could you please elaborate what the OP is supposed to try at Disk Management?

Comment: Maybe you could use a new Windows account.